# iOS Datasource not being set as expected of the TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, datasource

I have a `TableView` "`cannedTv`". Each cell contains another `TableView` "`valuesTv`". The structure of `datasource` for `cannedTv` is `{ NSString *name, NSArray *valuesArr }`. `valuesArr` is set as `datasource` for `valuesTv`. `cannedTv` is an expandable tableview. Initially just name is displayed, when expanded the valuesTv tableView is displayed. This is my code for `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate methods of the tableviews.

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"ROW Selected...TAG = %d", tableView.tag);
    selectedValueIndex = -1;

    if (tableView == self.cannedTV) {

        // USer taps expanded row
        if (selectedIndex == indexPath.row) {

            selectedIndex = -1;
            [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath ] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            return;
        }

        // USer taps differnt row
        if (selectedIndex != -1) {

            NSIndexPath *prevPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectedIndex inSection:0];
            selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
            [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:prevPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        }

        // User taps new row with none expanded
        selectedIndex = indexPath.row;

        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    } 
    return;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@"Table View TAG = %d  ROW = %d", tableView.tag, indexPath.row);

    if (tableView.tag == 10) {  //  cell.valuesTv
        CannedValueCell *ccell = (CannedValueCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cannedValueCell"];
        if (ccell == nil) {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CannedValueCell" owner:self options:nil];
            ccell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }

        // Populate valuesTv
        ccell.valueTextView.text = [valuesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(valueTextViewTapped)];
        [ccell.valueTextView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];

        //[ccell.valueTextView sizeToFit];
        return ccell;

    } else {
       // cannedTv
       static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CannedCell";

       cell = (CannedCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
       if(cell == nil) {
           NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CannedCell" owner:self options:nil];
           cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
       }

       // Set Datasource & Delegate for valuesTv tableview
       cell.valuesTv.dataSource = self;
       cell.valuesTv.delegate = self;

       if (selectedIndex == indexPath.row) {
           // Do expanded cell stuff
           [cell.tapInsertLbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans" size:8.0]];
           cell.tapInsertLbl.hidden = FALSE;

           [cell.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
           [cell.contentView.layer setBorderColor: (__bridge CGColorRef)([UIColor redColor])];
           [cell.contentView.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
       } else {
           // Do closed cell stuff
           cell.tapInsertLbl.hidden = TRUE;
           cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
       }

       if (tableView == self.cannedTV) {

           valuesArray = nil;
           CannedItem *ci = [candRespList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

           cell.tagLbl.text = ci.name;     
           // Set the valuesArray so it be used in populating the valuesTv
           valuesArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: ci.valuesArr];
           ci = nil;

       } else if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
           cell.tagLbl.text = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       }

       [cell.tagLbl sizeToFit];

       return cell;
    }

}
```

The problem I am facing is, every time the right `datasource` is shown shown in `valuesTv`. At this moment I have 2 arrays in valuesArray with 0th element having 1 object and 1st element having 3 objects (of NSString). `Datasource` of `cannedTv` also has 2 rows in it. Sometimes, one time both rows of `canndTv` shows correct datasource and then both shows same datasource. Sometimes, both rows shows the same datasource. I don't understand why `valuesArray` can't get the right datasource. While debugging also, I found that at times `valuesArray` has right datasource but the tableview is showing wrongly, at times the control doesn't go to `// Populates valuesTv` line and thus previously set `valuesArray` is only shown. I tried many ways, but can't get the results as expected. Also tried to set `valuesArray` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` after setting `selectedIndex`, but that also didn't help.

I am stuck on this since yesterday and can't get thru. Where am I going wrong due to which correct datasource is not shown/reflected on the tableviews. Can you please try to help me out. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks a lot.

**UPDATE :-**

Created new datasource & delegate in `CannedCell` object itself - it contains the `valuesTv`.

```
@interface CannedCell : UITableViewCell <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property NSArray *valuesDataSource;  // Contains the valuesArray contents
```

In my VC, removed datasource for `cell.values.datasource` & `cell.valuesTv.delegate` lines. In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method for top table, set the datasource like this :-

```
    if (tableView == self.cannedTV) {

    valuesArray = nil;
    CannedItem *ci = [candRespList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.tagLbl.text = ci.name;     //[tagsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //valuesArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: ci.valuesArr];

    cell.valuesDataSource = ci.valuesArr;  //  SET DATASOURCE
    // This is setting proper array always
    ci = nil;

}
```

Commented the whole `if (tableView.tag == 10) {` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

And in CannedCell :-

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
if (valuesDataSource != nil)
    return valuesDataSource.count;
else
    return 0;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

CannedValueCell *ccell = (CannedValueCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cannedValueCell"];
if (ccell == nil) {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CannedValueCell" owner:self options:nil];
    ccell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}

// Populate valuesTv
ccell.valueTextView.text = [valuesDataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
ccell.valueTextView.tag = indexPath.row;

return ccell;
```

}

Yet the results are as earlier only. I mean even if array of 3 objects are set as valuedDataSource, the sub-table shows only single object array. What do the think now can be the reason for this ?

Comment: Your problem is that in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you don't know which cell is being requested for sub-table views. You seem to have assumed that the method will be called for sub table views immediately after being called for the top-level table view cell (so you are setting `valuesArray`) but this isn't a valid assumption.  I would create another object class to act as the datasource and delegate for the sub table views

Comment: In one function you are checking if `if (tableView == self.cannedTV) ` and another you are checking `if (tableView.tag == 10)`, both mean it's `cannedTv`? Why are those not consistent? Is the tag check actually correct?

Comment: @ansible, tableview.tag == 10 indicates valuesTv i.e the sub-tableview. And cannedTv is the main tableview whose cell contains valuesTv.

Comment: @Paulw11, then how would you pass the data to the other object class to manage datasource & delegate of sub-table in my case. And how would that be helpful ?

Comment: I am not clear if you want to have the ability to expand multiple rows at once or only one, but either way the implementation would be similar.  Create a class to be the datasource and delegate for the subtable.  This class would also store its expanded state.  In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` for your top table you would create an instance of this new class for each cell, assign the appropriate sub-array and set it as the datasource and delegate for the table view in the cell.  Then you don't have to have all of this checking in one set of code trying to work out which table you are dealing with

Comment: @Paulw11, I want to expand only single cell at a time & have implemented that part & its working perfectly fine. I am not sure if I got your point clearly - how about setting the top table's cell subclass as datasource & delegate for its sub table. CannedCell : UITableViewCell <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> . So in cellForRowAtIndexPath, I can pass the datasource i.e. valuesArray for each cell for its sub-table.

Comment: @Paulw11, I implemented as you suggested, but yet results appear to be the same. Though I didn't implement anything for storing expanded state, as am not clear what to do with it.

Comment: @Paulw11, after setting the datasource for valuesDataSource, I called [cell.valuesTv reloadData]; and this did the work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Paulw11, I created other object to handle TableViewDelegate and datasource for the sub-table. Though that didn't make any difference in the results of the problem.

I set UITableViewDelegate & Datasource in my top table's Cell class. Passed the array to be the datasource of the table.

Importantly, after setting the datasource of sub-table on calling

```
[cell.valuesTv reloadData]
```

forced the sub-table to reload its data and that finally did the trick. Till then things weren't working.